# Exposing data from connected tables in Entity Framework Core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My app has tables of Product, ProductTags, Tags. I can access ProductTags from Products e.g. Product.ProductTags. I can access a single Tag by looping through Product.ProductTags as follows:

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
foreach (var pt in product.ProductTags)
{
   tags.Add(pt.Tag);
}
```

However, is there an easy way to be able to access a list of all Tags for a Product e.g. Product.Tags rather than have to iterate through the ProductTags list to expose each individual tag? And then similarly to make it easier when writing the tags back.

My models are as follows, albeit with some fields removed to make easier to read:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // ID (Primary key)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name
    
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
    public Product()
    {
        ProductTags = new List<ProductTag>();
    }
 }

 public class ProductTag
 {
    public int ProductTagId { get; set; } 
    public int TagId { get; set; } 
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } 
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }       
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; } // TagID (Primary key)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name
    
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; } 

    public Tag()
    {
        ProductTags = new List<ProductTag>();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
In my ProductController, this is how I retrieve the data:

```
var product = await _context.Products
   .Include(pt => pt.ProductTags)
   .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

This gives me a list as product.ProductTags, but not product.Tags.

Ultimately, I would like to edit the tag list for the product, so do something like this example where I can pass in a list of tags to add or remove:

```
public virtual void AddTags(IEnumerable<Tag> tags, TagType tagType, Product product)
{
    if (tags == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tags");
    if (tags.Count(t => t.TagType != tagType) > 0) throw new ArgumentException("Tags of multiple types supplied");

    var tagsToRemove = product.Tags.Where(t => !tags.Contains(t) && t.TagType == tagType).ToList();
    foreach (var t in tagsToRemove)
        this.Tags.Remove(t);

    foreach (var t in tags)
        if (!this.Tags.Contains(t))
            this.Tags.Add(t);
    }
```

Comment: Use eager or explicit loading. [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: Thanks, but with the model as it is I can only include Product.ProductTags, not Product.Tags this way, so I presume my model needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

> You can use the Include method to specify related data to be included in query results:

```
var products = context.Products
        .Include(m => m.ProductTags)
        .ToList();
```

You can also include multiple navigation properties:

```
var products = context.Products
            .Include(m => m.Tags)
            .Include(m => m.ProductTags)
```

Or even include the `Tag` from the `ProductTags`-Property with `ThenInclude()`:

```
var products = context.Products
                .Include(m => m.ProductTags)
                .ThenInclude(m => m.Tag)
```